# Use string to select location in data frame to store value

Tags: r, loops, lapply, paste

I have a loop that runs through models. The loop generates multiple formulas that are inserted into the model command and then processed for backward step selection using `buildmer()`. Using a `lapply()` function it does this for each data frame in a list called Species. The problem is I need to store the results in different data frames so as to not get them confused.

A simplified example of the code is:

```
lapply(Species, function(x){

  for (i in 1:10){
    LRm<-buildmer(formula = form.LR, family = 'binomial', control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"), data=x, crit= c('AIC'), direction = c("order", "backward"))


 #Get the species name for current model

  ID<-colnames(DIKDIK) %>%
  .[grepl("ADULTS",.)]%>%
  sub("*.ADULTS", "", .)

 paste0(ID)$AIC[i]<-AIC(LRm)

  }
})
```

EDIT: form.LR is the model formula which is created anew for each iteration but this code is omitted since it is irrelevant

It will become apparent that as the code reaches the second value for x (that is running the model for the second data frame) the results will be overwritten from the results from the first since the same indexes for 'i' are being used. Therein lies the problem.

Note that I can identify which data frame was used by selecting the colname with a partial match to  "ADULTS" using `grepl()` for which the full column name is unique in each data frame. So I thought I could name each data frame by this string i.e. "GIRAFFE" and use it to identify where the data should be stored. But I don't seem to be able to find the right combination of `paste()`. And I am not even sure if what I am trying is possible.

The current code breaks down giving the error

```
Error in paste0(ID)[[i]] <- NA : could not find function "paste0<-"
```

I didn't find any other solutions to similar problems on SO so far.

A simplified reproducible example of the Species list object would be

```
ADULTS.GIRAFFE<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)
ADULTS.DIKDIK<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)
ADULTS.IMPALA<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)

presence1<-rbinom(20, 1, .5)
presence2<-rbinom(20, 1, .5)
presence3<-rbinom(20, 1, .5)

var1<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)
var2<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)
var3<-rnorm(20, 3, sd=1)

a<-cbind(presence1, var1, var2, var3, ADULTS.GIRAFFE)
b<-cbind(presence1, var1, var2, var3, ADULTS.DIKDIK)
c<-cbind(presence1, var1, var2, var3, ADULTS.IMPALA)

Species<-list(a,b,c)
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a reproducible example of the structure of `Species`, or even included the output of `dput(head(Species[[1]]))` in your question. Plus, what is `form.LR`? There are some clever people on this site, but to my knowledge none of them are psychic! I can however see a couple of problems with your code. Isn't LRm going to give the same result 10 times for each data frame in your list? The `for(i in 1:10){ ...` loop, seems to run the same model 10 times. Also the function in `lapply` doesn't `return` anything. You need to `return` an object which `lapply` will add to a list.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for your interest and comments I have edited my question accordingly. Please ask if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the data frames as a list allowed me to name each data frame in the list as so:

```
snames<-c("DIKDIK","THOMSONS", "GIRAFFE", "GRANTS", "IMPALA")

OutsLR<-lapply(snames, function(x){

  x<-data.frame()%>%
    insertRows(., 499, new = NA)%>%
    mutate(Number=NA)%>%
    mutate(AIC=NA)%>%
    mutate(Model=NA)

})

#Rename the data frames in the list
names(Outs) = snames
```

Then selecting the data frame using the string object called ID was easy

```
#Just for the example
ID<-"DIKDIK"

#Then 
OutsLR[[ID]][["AIC"]][i]<-AIC(LRm)
```